# Which downloadable launchers are based on the ICS stock launcher?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, launcher

After upgrading to ICS, I'd like to use either the stock ICS launcher or an improved version based on it. What are my options?

Comment: We don't do lists like this, sorry.  Might be a good question for the chatroom, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher)
- [Apex Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher)
- [Trebuchet (CM9's official launcher)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1410674)

As far as I know, you must install all of these to `/system` (which requires root) in order to have widgets appear in the app drawer, and Trebuchet doesn't support being installed to `/data` at all.